# .NET Core 5.0 Console with WebAPI

Tags: .net-core, console, webapi, .net-5

I once build a .NET Core Console App that contained a web host, so I could make controllers without using IIS. Isn't that possible in 5.0?

I need it to run as a service later. It used to be so easy :-)

I can't find any guides to that, but I can find guids addressing version 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest .NET Core project templates (and .NET 5 ones) use Kestrel by default.
You can find the related documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

You can also find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-up-a-process-manager) specific documentation about running ASP .NET Core as a service in both Windows and Linux, and in the case of Windows, with and without IIS.